# BIRT map value to different output

Tags: birt

I am trying to use the map option, so it seems to be possible to change the output of a data field (ie: if the field contains the text G the report must display the value Google).
Created the rule but in the output i am still getting G.

Does anyone know which could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the instructions in this link: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Ffm-HowToMapDataValuesToDifferentDisplayValues.html

Make sure to compare using Equal to "G" (note the quotation marks).